# Java: OpenGL ES 2.0, view clipping

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a problem with an Orthographic projection, isometric camera view, where objects I draw far away from center 0, 0, 0 on a scene is clipped even if the objects is placed in the view.

In the **onSurfaceChanged** method I have:

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
final float ratio = (float) width / height;

final float left = -ratio;
final float right = ratio;
final float bottom = -1.0f;
final float top = 1.0f;
final float near = 1.0f;
final float far = 10.0f;

int useForOrtho = Math.min(width, height);
mProjectionMatrix = createOrthoProjectionMatrix(left, right, top, bottom, near, far);
Matrix.orthoM(mViewMatrix, 0,
            -useForOrtho / 2,
            useForOrtho / 2,
            -useForOrtho / 2,
            useForOrtho / 2, 0.01f, 100.0f);

Matrix.rotateM(mViewMatrix, 0, 45, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(mViewMatrix, 0, 35, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Here is the function for the **projection matrix**:

```
public float[] createOrthoProjectionMatrix(float left, float right, float top, float bottom, float near, float far)
{

    float[] m = new float[16];

    m[0] = 2.0f / (right - left);
    m[1] = 0.0f;
    m[2] = 0.0f;
    m[3] = 0.0f;

    m[4] = 0.0f;
    m[5] = 2.0f / (top - bottom);
    m[6] = 0.0f;
    m[7] = 0.0f;

    m[8] = 0.0f;
    m[9] = 0.0f;
    m[10] = -2.0f / (far - near);
    m[11] = 0.0f;

    m[12] = -(right + left  ) / (right - left  );
    m[13] = -(top   + bottom) / (top   - bottom);
    m[14] = -(far   + near  ) / (far   - near  );
    m[15] = 1.0f;

    return m;
}
```

Where can I control how far out on x, y, z away from 0, 0, 0 that objects can be drawn without being clipped? The problem objects isn't placed "out of view", but more like out of the current rendervolume - out of distance - having triangles clipped.

Comment: Treat far as infinity. So m[10] will be 0, m[14] = -1. Or -infinity...

Comment: The thing is, if you want to have z-buffer working you need to specify a volume that spawns some reasonable amount in order to have sorting working within the floating point value.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick